# Why can lstlisting not be saved in a command?

Tags: macros, listings

This code fails with `Emergency stop`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand{\demo}{%
\begin{lstlisting}
foobar
\end{lstlisting}
}

\begin{document}
\demo
\end{document}
```

Why?

Comment: Because `lstlisting` has to play with category codes and putting it into the definition of a command inhibits category code changes.

Comment: SEE: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23744/verbatim-text-cant-be-shown-correctly-in-pdf/23746#23746

Comment: You can use '\lstnewenvironment{code}'. See  (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60867/create-a-lstnewenvironment-that-creates-named-listings)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your code the whole `lstlisting` code is read as a macro argument before the code is executed. When (La)TeX reads some code it does some processing like it strips comments, combines multiple spaces to one, converts line breaks to spaces and two line breaks in a row to `\par` etc.

However, the `lstlisting` environment and all other verbatim environments or macros want to have all of these characters (space, line break, comment characters) in their unchanged, verbatim form. For this the change the internal configuration of them by alter the so called *category codes* (catcodes), so that e.g. `%` is now a normal character and doesn't start a comment any longer, the `\` doesn't start a macro any longer etc.

Now, when the code is already read as part of a macro argument all catcodes have already be assigned to the characters and some have already be transformed as mentioned above, so that the changes made by the verbatim environment afterwards when it is executed do not have any effects any longer.

In general there is the rule that verbatim material can't be used inside a macro argument or pseudo-environment (an environment which reads its whole content, see e.g. the `environ` package, but also `tabularx` does it). Luckily boxes are read and processed like normal text, so you can use e.g. the `lrbox` environment to store the `lstlisting` in a savebox and use it later using `\usebox`. However, you can't use the `\sbox` or `\savebox` macro because they read the content also as macro argument. I wrote the `realboxes` package just to provide alternatives which read the content as box, so you could use `\Sbox` and `\Savebox` instead after loading that package.

Comment: Is it possible to expand your answer with a MWE?

Comment: MWE means "minimum working example" to anyone unfamiliar and had to google it, like myself...

Answer (score 10):

The [`listings` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) provides some experimental features that allows you to capture it in a macro/command. However, as stated in the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf), this is not advised (section **5.1 Listings inside arguments**, p 46):

> There are some things to consider if you want to use `\lstinline` or
>   the `lstlisting` environment inside arguments. Since TeX reads the
>   argument before the `lst`-macro is executed, this package can't do
>   anything to preserve the input: spaces shrink to one space, the
>   tabulator and the end of line are converted to spaces, TeX's comment
>   character is not printable, and so on. Hence, you must work a bit
>   more. You have to put a backslash in front of each of the following
>   four characters: `\{}%`. Moreover you must protect spaces in the same
>   manner if: (i) there are two or more spaces following each other or
>   (ii) the space is the ﬁrst character in the line. That's not enough:
>   Each line must be terminated with a "line feed" `^^J`. And you can’t
>   escape to LaTeX inside such listings! ... You might wonder that this
>   feature is still experimental. The reason: You shouldn't use listings
>   inside arguments; it’s not always safe!

As such, the following works:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand{\demo}{%
\begin{lstlisting}^^J
foobar^^J
\end{lstlisting}
}

\begin{document}
\demo

Some text

\demo
\end{document}
```

[image: lstlisting via a macro]

---

This does not answer your question, but instead provides a different work-around, if you're interested. Not sure how effective this is in general, but you can store an `lstlisting` in a box (using the [`lrbox` environment](http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex2e/latex2e_145.html)). That is, I'm not sure whether there are some limitation that may stem from options passed to a `lstlisting` environment. It works for this minimal case.:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\begin{document}
\newsavebox{\mylisting}
\begin{lrbox}{\mylisting}
  \begin{lstlisting}
    foobar
  \end{lstlisting}%
\end{lrbox}

\usebox{\mylisting}% Print box mylisting

Some text.

\usebox{\mylisting}% Print box mylisting
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `\box0`: Matthias wants to define `\demo` in the preamble and use it afterwards, so a box register should be allocated.

Comment: The [`lrbox`](http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex2e/latex2e_145.html) environment instead of `\setbox` would be better here because it adds the required internal color commands. Otherwise there might be color issues when placing the saved box.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Thanks for the suggestion; modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: Adding the `minipage` environment to manually set the width might also be useful.

Comment: @Werner thanks for the useful answer!! How can we create a command `\mycode` using your second code? I tried with `\newcommand{\mycode}[1]{ \newsavebox{\mylisting} \begin{lrbox}{\mylisting} \begin{lstlisting}#1\end{lstlisting} \end{lrbox}}` and `\mycode{Test}` with errors.

Comment: @manooooh: Will it only include single line code elements, used inline or a block?

Comment: @Werner thanks for your support. I need two commands: `\myblockcode` has to use `\begin{lstlisting}` and `\myinlinecode` has to use `\lstinline`. Both commands should have the same format (I will use VB.NET language for both but since it is not part of the `listings` package I will have to define its format.) Context here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/531204/152550

Comment: @manooooh: Sorry, but I'm currently too busy too help out with this...

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the use of boxes given by @Werner is to use the `scontents` package. This allows to store in memory contents `verbatim` to be reused later (it can also be written in external files).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scontents}
\usepackage{listings}
\Scontents*{%
\begin{lstlisting}
foobar
\end{lstlisting}
}

\begin{scontents}
\begin{lstlisting}
barfoo
\end{lstlisting}
\end{scontents}

\begin{document}
Some text

\getstored[2]{contents}

Some text

\getstored[1]{contents}

\getstored[2]{contents}
\end{document}
```

It is preferable to manage the environment version (managing space using the command version is a bit tedious).
Saludos