# redefine shorthand for single line listings

Tags: macros, listings

I would like to redefine a short command (without `\begin` ... `\end`) for single line code examples using the `listings` package.

Here is what I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\my}[1]{
\begin{lstlisting}
#1
\end{lstlisting}
}

\begin{document}
\my{code}
\end{document}
```

However, it gives the following error:

```
! Emergency stop.
<*> example.tex
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)
```

Using lstlisting directly works, though:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're trying to handle verbatim code (listing environment) inside an argument-- this does not work! In my opinion, such shorthands are not useful in 99.9 % of all cases anyway. They will prove as shoot in the foot in the long turn

Comment: Short version: you can't do this. See e.g. [Why can lstlisting not be saved in a command?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29971)