# Listing in a command error: Text dropped after begin of listing on input line

Tags: macros, errors, listings

While I wanted to test some alignment options to ask another question regarding to `listings`, I have encountered a problem that I was not expecting.

Consider the following code:

```
% Preamble
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt, onecolumn]{article}

% Packages
\usepackage{listings}

% Lst options
\lstset{
    language = C++,
    frame = lines,
    framesep = 0pt,
    rulesep = 0pt,
    aboveskip = 0pt,
    belowskip = 0pt,
}

% Commands
\newcommand{\alphabet}{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}
\newcommand{\makelisting}[1]{
\newpage\noindent\alphabet
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle = \fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont#1]
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\alphabet
}

% Document
\begin{document}
\makelisting{\tiny}
\makelisting{\scriptsize}
\makelisting{\footnotesize}
\makelisting{\small}
\makelisting{\normalsize}
\makelisting{\large}
\makelisting{\Large}
\makelisting{\LARGE}
\makelisting{\huge}
\makelisting{\Huge}
\end{document}
```

It should be pretty straightforward. However, I end up with the following error:

```
Package Listings Warning: Text dropped after begin of listing on input line 32.
```

and no file is produced. Where this is coming from, and how to make it work?

Comment: Maybe you are interested in [Why can lstlisting not be saved in a command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29971/134144)

Comment: As leandriis mentions, listings like all other verbatim like constructions cannot be used inside macros.

Comment: Is there a way to pass an argument (here the size) to a savebox? How can I do the thing I want to do using savebox? (I would validate an answer that would do that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no other way than to save the sample code in a file.

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-sample.c}
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

% Packages
\usepackage{listings}

% Lst options
\lstset{
    language = C++,
    frame = lines,
    framesep = 0pt,
    rulesep = 0pt,
    aboveskip = 0pt,
    belowskip = 0pt,
}

% Commands
\newcommand{\alphabet}{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}
\newcommand{\makelisting}[1]{%
  \bigskip\noindent\alphabet
  \lstinputlisting[basicstyle = \fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont#1]{\jobname-sample.c}
  \alphabet\par
}

% Document
\begin{document}
\makelisting{\tiny}
\makelisting{\scriptsize}
\makelisting{\footnotesize}
\makelisting{\small}
\makelisting{\normalsize}
\makelisting{\large}
\makelisting{\Large}
\makelisting{\LARGE}
\makelisting{\huge}
%\makelisting{\Huge}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is have LaTeX read and tokenize your code listing under verbatim category code régime and pass it into the definition of `\makelisting` wrapped into a call to `\scantokens`.

For having LaTeX read and tokenize things under verbatim category code régime I often use my routine `\UDcollectverbarg` which has the following syntax:

`\UDcollectverbarg{⟨^^M-replacement⟩}{⟨Mandatory 1⟩}{⟨Mandatory 2⟩}⟨verbatimized argument⟩`

This yields:

`⟨Mandatory 1⟩{⟨Mandatory 2⟩{⟨verbatimized argument⟩}}`

, with each character `^^M` that denotes an end of a line being replaced by the token-sequence `⟨^^M-replacement⟩`.

The arguments `⟨Mandatory 1⟩` and `⟨Mandatory 2⟩` are mandatory. If they consist of several tokens, they must be nested into a catcode-1/2-character-pair / into braces.
If reading and tokenizing is necessary for obtaining some of them, this will take place under unchanged category code régime.
The `⟨verbatimized argument⟩` is also mandatory. **It is to be read and tokenized from the .tex-input file** under verbatim category code régime. If its first character is a brace, it will be "assumed" that that argument is nested into braces.  Otherwise it will be assumed, that the ending of that argument is delimited by that first character—like the argument of `\verb`.
Empty-lines will not be ignored.

I chose this syntax as with this syntax you can collect verbatimized arguments within the `⟨Mandatory 2⟩`-argument by nesting calls to `\UDcollectverbarg` within `\UDcollectverbarg`'s `⟨Mandatory 1⟩`-argument.

E.g.,

```
\UDcollectverbarg{⟨^^M-replacement⟩}%
                 {\UDcollectverbarg{⟨^^M-replacement⟩}{\UDcollectverbarg{⟨^^M-replacement⟩}{⟨actionA⟩}}}%  <- Mandatory 1
                 {⟨actionB⟩}%                     <- Mandatory 2
                 ⟨verbatimized argument 1⟩⟨verbatimized argument 2⟩⟨verbatimized argument 3⟩
```

yields:

```
\UDcollectverbarg{⟨^^M-replacement⟩}{\UDcollectverbarg{⟨^^M-replacement⟩}{⟨actionA⟩}}% <- Mandatory 1
                 {⟨actionB⟩{⟨verbatimized argument 1⟩}}%        <- Mandatory 2
                 ⟨verbatimized argument 2⟩⟨verbatimized argument 3⟩
```

yields:

```
\UDcollectverbarg{⟨^^M-replacement⟩}{⟨actionA⟩}% <- Mandatory 1
                 {⟨actionB⟩{⟨verbatimized argument 1⟩}{⟨verbatimized argument 2⟩}}% <- Mandatory 2
                 ⟨verbatimized argument 3⟩
```

yields:

```
⟨actionA⟩{⟨actionB⟩{⟨verbatimized argument 1⟩}{⟨verbatimized argument 2⟩}{⟨verbatimized argument 3⟩}}
```

Assume `⟨actionA⟩` = `\@firstofone`:

```
\@firstofone{⟨actionB⟩{⟨verbatimized argument 1⟩}{⟨verbatimized argument 2⟩}{⟨verbatimized argument 3⟩}}
```

yields:

```
⟨actionB⟩{⟨verbatimized argument 1⟩}{⟨verbatimized argument 2⟩}{⟨verbatimized argument 3⟩}
```

Here comes the example:

```
% Preamble
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt, onecolumn]{article}

% Adjust horizontal margins so that listings in \Huge fits on paper also:
\makeatletter
\setlength\evensidemargin{2.2cm}%
\setlength\marginparsep{.25\evensidemargin}%
\setlength\marginparwidth{.5\evensidemargin}%
\setlength\oddsidemargin{\if@twoside.5\fi\evensidemargin}%
\setlength\textwidth\paperwidth
\addtolength\textwidth{-\if@twoside1.5\else2\fi\evensidemargin}%
\addtolength\evensidemargin{-1in}%
\addtolength\oddsidemargin{-1in}%
\@ifundefined{pdfpagewidth}{}{\setlength\pdfpagewidth{\paperwidth}}%
\@ifundefined{pdfpageheight}{}{\setlength\pdfpageheight{\paperheight}}%
\@ifundefined{pagewidth}{}{\setlength\pagewidth{\paperwidth}}%
\@ifundefined{pageheight}{}{\setlength\pageheight{\paperheight}}%
\makeatother

% Packages
\usepackage{listings}

% Lst options
\lstset{
    language = C++,
    frame = lines,
    framesep = 0pt,
    rulesep = 0pt,
    aboveskip = 0pt,
    belowskip = 0pt,
}

% Commands
\newcommand{\alphabet}{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}

%%<..................Paraphernalia.....................................>
\makeatletter
\newcommand\UD@firstofone[1]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
%%<-------------------- Code for \UDcollectverbarg -------------------->
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%......................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \UD@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%......................................................................
\begingroup
\catcode`\^^M=12 %
\UD@firstofone{%
  \endgroup%
  \newcommand\UDEndlreplace[2]{\romannumeral0\@UDEndlreplace{#2}#1^^M\relax{}}%
  \newcommand*\@UDEndlreplace{}%
  \long\def\@UDEndlreplace#1#2^^M#3\relax#4#5{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#3}%
    { #5{#4#2}}{\@UDEndlreplace{#1}#3\relax{#4#2#1}{#5}}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UDcollectverbarg[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\do\@makeother % <- this and the next line switch to
  \dospecials        %    verbatim-category-code-régime.
  \catcode`\{=1      % <- give opening curly brace the usual catcode so a 
                     %    curly-brace-balanced argument can be gathered in
                     %    case of the first thing of the verbatimized-argument 
                     %    being a curly opening brace.
  \catcode`\ =10     % <- give space and horizontal tab the usual catcode so \UD@collectverbarg
  \catcode`\^^I=10   %    cannot catch a space or a horizontal tab as its 4th undelimited argument.
                     %    (Its 4th undelimited argument denotes the verbatim-
                     %     syntax-delimiter in case of not gathering a
                     %     curly-brace-nested argument.)
  \kernel@ifnextchar\bgroup
  {% seems a curly-brace-nested argument is to be caught:
    \catcode`\}=2    % <- give closing curly brace the usual catcode also.
    \UD@collectverbarg{#1}{#2}{#3}{}%
  }{% seems an argument with verbatim-syntax-delimiter is to be caught:
    \do\{% <- give opening curly brace the verbatim-catcode again.
    \UD@collectverbarg{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@collectverbarg[4]{%
  \do\ %   <- Now that \UD@collectverbarg has the delimiter or
  \do\^^I%    emptiness in its 4th arg, give space and horizontal tab
         %    the verbatim-catcode again.
  \do\^^M% <- Give the carriage-return-character the verbatim-catcode.
  \long\def\@tempb##1#4{%
    %\edef\@tempb{##1}%
    \def\@tempb{##1}%
    \@onelevel@sanitize\@tempb % <- Turn characters into their "12/other"-pendants.
                               %    This may be important with things like the 
                               %    inputenc-package which may make characters 
                               %    active/which give them catcode 13(active).
    \expandafter\UDEndlreplace\expandafter{\@tempb}{#1}{\def\@tempb}% <- this starts 
                               %    the loop for replacing endline-characters.
    \expandafter\UD@@collectverbarg\expandafter{\@tempb}{#2}{#3}% <- this "spits 
                               %    out the result.
  }%
  \@tempb
}%
\newcommand\UD@@collectverbarg[3]{%
  \endgroup
  #2{#3{#1}}%
}%
\makeatother
%%<---------------- End of code for \UDcollectverbarg ----------------->

\makeatletter
\begingroup
\newcommand\makelisting[2]{%
  \endgroup
  \newcommand\makelisting[1]{%
    \newpage
    \noindent\alphabet
    \scantokens{%
      \par\noindent #1##1#2%
    }%
    \alphabet
  }%
}%
\UDcollectverbarg{^^J}%
                 {%
                   \UDcollectverbarg{^^J}%
                                     {\UD@firstofone}%
                 }%
                 {\makelisting}|\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle = \fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont||]
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
%|

\makeatother

%\show\makelisting

\begin{document}
\makelisting{\tiny}
\makelisting{\scriptsize}
\makelisting{\footnotesize}
\makelisting{\small}
\makelisting{\normalsize}
\makelisting{\large}
\makelisting{\Large}
\makelisting{\LARGE}
\makelisting{\huge}
\makelisting{\Huge}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]