# Use `tikzpicture` in `\newcommand` or `\newenvironment` along with `lstlisting`

Tags: tikz-pgf, environments

I defined the following command `\recomm` to print a box with a separated body and a title:

```
\newcommand{\recomm}[3]{
  \vspace{0.5cm}
  \noindent 
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [rectangle, inner sep=10pt] (box){%
        \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-20pt-\pgflinewidth\relax}
            #2
        \end{minipage}
    };
    \node [rectangle, inner sep=10pt, fill=black!15, below right] (box2) at (box.south west){%
        \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-20pt-\pgflinewidth\relax}
            #3
        \end{minipage}
    };
    \draw[draw=blue!75!black, very thick] 
      -- (box2.south west)
      -- (box.north west)
      -- (box.north east)
      -- (box2.south east)
      -- (box2.south west);
    \node[above right, fill=blue!75!black, text=white, font=\bfseries] at (box.north west) {#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

This works fine and prints a nice box when used with simple input:

```
\recomm{Title}{%
  Some content in the first part
}{%
  Some content in the second part
}
```

[image: Working box]

However, when I try to insert a code listing using the `lstlisting` environment, I'm getting all sorts of errors:

```
\recomm{Title}{%
  Some content in the first part
}{%
  Some content in the second part

  \begin{lstlisting}
    a=b
  \end{lstlisting}
}
```

```
Argument of \lst@next has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.185 }
```

I tried using `\newenvironment`, but that allows only for a single environment where I need two (the first and second part of the picture). What is the recommended way to solve this nicely?

(I'd like to avoid tcolorbox, as I have to work with a very incomplete texlive environment where that package and many of its dependencies are not included.)

---

Minimal not working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\recomm}[2]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [rectangle, inner sep=10pt] (box){%
        \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-20pt-\pgflinewidth\relax}
            #1
        \end{minipage}
    };
    \node [rectangle, inner sep=10pt, fill=black!15, below right] (box2) at (box.south west){%
        \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-20pt-\pgflinewidth\relax}
            #2
        \end{minipage}
    };
}

\begin{document}

\recomm{%
  Some content in the first part
}{%
  Some content in the second part

  \begin{lstlisting}
    a=b
  \end{lstlisting}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Listings and other types of verbatim link constructions cannot generally be used in arguments for macros. Make an env based interface instead and that will probably work. Also have a look at the `tcolorbox` package which probably include what you are looking for.

Comment: Additionally next time please incldue a full minimal self contained example instead of just a sniplet. Users are much less likely to help if thye have to guess part of a document in order to test your code.

Comment: In addition to what @daleif is saying, `tcolorbox` allows you to use all Ti*k*Z commands for your boxes using `overlay`. (The depicted box does not need that, it is very easy to reproduce it with `tcolorbox` without `overlay`, I think.)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I'll provide a minimal (not-)working example in a minute. As stated in my question, I can't use `tcolorbox`.

Comment: You may want to look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29971 to see how much effort it will be to accomplish what you want. `tcolorbox` does a lot of things behind the scenes, you'd basically have to redo them. Personally I would think it would be easier to fix the dependencies on your installation.