# New command using inline verbatim

Tags: verbatim, fancyvrb

I would like to define a command using verbatim like in the commented line in the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

%   \newcommand{\example}[1]{\verb!#1! : #1}

\begin{document}

\noindent \verb!$\textbf{A}^\intercal$! : $\textbf{A}^\intercal$
\\
\example{$\textbf{A}^\intercal$}$

\end{document}
```

How can I acheive this? Is it possible to give the argument without the dollars?

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23744/verbatim-text-cant-be-shown-correctly-in-pdf/23746#23746

Comment: Thanks for the link but it does not help me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question that @Marco refers to [Verbatim text can't be shown correctly in pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23744/verbatim-text-cant-be-shown-correctly-in-pdf/23746#23746) and the referenced [Why doesn’t verbatim work within](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-verbwithin)  attempt to explain the difficulties with verbatim commands within macros.

But based on your code in the MWE `\newcommand{\example}[1]{\verb!#1! : #1}`
it appears that you want to be able to show the LaTeX code and its output:

[image]

One way to do that would be to use the `LTXexample` environment from [the `showexpl` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/showexpl):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{showexpl}

\lstdefinestyle{demoLatexStyle}{
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    numbers=none,
    frame=none,
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow},
    pos=r
}

\begin{document}
\begin{LTXexample}[style=demoLatexStyle]
$\textbf{A}^\intercal$
\end{LTXexample}
\end{document}
```