# Setting up specific font for use in listings

Tags: fonts, listings

I'm writing my dissertion using TeX. I would like to use a specific font in my `lstlisting` source code. How can I use a specific font like Monaco or Arial? I usually found solutions with `basicstyle` setted to `\ttfamily` but it's not what I want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Verbatim text can't be shown correctly in pdf](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23744/verbatim-text-cant-be-shown-correctly-in-pdf)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Altough it may seem trivial it is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Why should this be a duplicate of that question?

Comment: @egreg: I am showing how you can set the font with the package `listings` and `fancyvrb`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel It's rather hidden in the definition of another environment.

Comment: @egreg: I think the op is searching something like `\lstset{basicstyle=\fontsize{10pt}{10}\usefont{OT1}{ptm}{m}{n}}`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Linking this to that question can give the false impression that it's necessary to define a new listing environment.

Comment: @egreg: Now I understand your caveat. I think for absolute beginners you are right.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 19):

You can't use a font in TeX unless it's known to the TeX system. For example Monaco isn't, unless you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX on Mac OS X. A good typewriter font for `pdflatex` can be BeraMono:

```
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
```

and then `\ttfamily` will use this font. You can say also `scaled=.85` or some other number, in order to accommodate the size to your main font.

There's a clone of Courier

```
\usepackage{tgcursor}
```

that sports a neat distinction between medium and bold weight (but might not agree with your main font).

However, you're not forced to use typewriter type for listings; if you say

```
\lstset{basicstyle=\sffamily}
```

you'll get whatever sans serif font is the default. You can change the default font by loading the suitable package; for example

```
\usepackage{tgheros}
```

will load a clone of Helvetica as the sans serif font and the above declaration will make this one the default. This package has a `scale` option similar to the `scaled` for **beramono**. Note that Arial is not considered to be a free font, so it's not in standard TeX distributions.

If you're using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX as typesetting engines, then you can use whatever OpenType or TrueType font you have on your system. For example, after having loaded **fontspec** you can define a suitable command

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
...
\newfontfamily{\lstsansserif}[Scale=.85]{Arial}
```

and then `\lstset{basicstyle=\lstsansserif}` would use Arial for listings.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of `\ttfamily` you can use all the other commands which select a font. E.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont} %Zapf

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
abcde
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```