# Highlighting Java Code like Bitcoin Whitepaper

Tags: code

In Bitcoin Whitepaper ( https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf ) on page 7, there is a C code snippet. The style, font and the size is very neat and proper. How can I apply this kind of style for my java code in TexStudio ( I am using TexLive)?

This is my java code:

```
import java.math.*;

public class successAttackerProbability {

public double calculateSuccessProbability(double q, int z) {
    int i, k;
    double p = 1.0 - q;
    double lambda = z * (q / p);
    double sum = 1.0;
    for (k = 0; k <= z; k++) {
        double poisson = Math.pow(Math.E, -lambda);

        for (i = 1; i <= k; i++)
            poisson *= lambda / i;
        sum -= poisson * (1 - Math.pow(q / p, z - k));

    }
    System.out.println(sum);
    return sum;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    successAttackerProbability successAttackerProbability = new successAttackerProbability();
    successAttackerProbability.calculateSuccessProbability(0.1, 1); // q =0.1 and z = 1
    successAttackerProbability.calculateSuccessProbability(0.1, 2);
    // ..
    successAttackerProbability.calculateSuccessProbability(0.1, 10);

}

}
```

Comment: Why not? Could you add some code and descripe your problem with it? A small minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem would be great.

Comment: Well, I just did it with $ \lstinputlisting{successAttackerProbability.java} $ , that's it, but I want the style like in the whitepaper.

Comment: (*describe. ). - Does `\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}` see daleifs answer solves your style problem? - Question without working code are harder to solve... compilable minimal code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, helps a lot.

Comment: It solves my problem regarding to font color. Now, I have to change the font. Do you have any examples? If not, I will google :)

Comment: `ttfamily `is the font or i'm wrong? - Related[Setting up specific font for use in listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34363/124842)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like plain verbatim, or the `listings` package with the `basicstyle` set to contain `\ttfamily`.

Example

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=JAVA,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
%  columns=flexible,
  breaklines,
  breakatwhitespace,
}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
import java.math.*;

public class successAttackerProbability {

public double calculateSuccessProbability(double q, int z) {
    int i, k;
    double p = 1.0 - q;
    double lambda = z * (q / p);
    double sum = 1.0;
    for (k = 0; k <= z; k++) {
        double poisson = Math.pow(Math.E, -lambda);

        for (i = 1; i <= k; i++)
            poisson *= lambda / i;
        sum -= poisson * (1 - Math.pow(q / p, z - k));

    }
    System.out.println(sum);
    return sum;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    successAttackerProbability successAttackerProbability = new successAttackerProbability();
    successAttackerProbability.calculateSuccessProbability(0.1, 1); // q =0.1 and z = 1
    successAttackerProbability.calculateSuccessProbability(0.1, 2);
    // ..
    successAttackerProbability.calculateSuccessProbability(0.1, 10);

}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

See the `listings` package manual for details.