# minted/fancyvrb environment as argument to TikZ command

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, verbatim, minted, fancyvrb

I want to create a command, accepting an argument, which sets the content of the argument as a TikZ picture. Problem: The argument is a `minted`/FancyVrb environment.

MWE:

```
%!TEX OPTIONS = --shell-escape
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{minted}
\newcommand{\tikzverb}[1]{\tikz{\node (text) [draw=blue, thick] {#1}; \fill [opacity=0.5] (text.north east) circle (5pt);}}
\begin{document}
\tikzverb{
\begin{minted}{text}
test
\end{minted}
}
\end{document}
```

Some background: This MWE is boiled down and simplified from a command from my slides, which I set via LaTeX Beamer. I configured `minted` for source code highlighting, so I'd rather use this package instead of other verbatim environments. In the slides, the command should display [bash shell output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xxxrori006fyeyf/fauxshell.pdf?dl=0).
During assembling of this MWE, I found out that using a savebox does not solve the issue, which was usually one of the solutions in other [questions](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/28) like this. A combination of savebox and `lstlisting` environments works (see also [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23744/verbatim-text-cant-be-shown-correctly-in-pdf/23746#23746)), but that'd mean another package which needs to be configured separately. I rather stick to `minted`, if I can (because it's great).

Comment: tcolorbox supports minted and making a background box.

Comment: Didn't know `tcolorbox`. Although it's another abstraction layer on top, let's see how far I come! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not directly answer my posed question, but the underlying problem (creating a fake bash shell). As suggested by @TeXnician, I use `tcolorbox` (which indeed is another package with all kind of new commands; but it's quite awesome).

I'm happy with the result: [image]

Any further suggestions to improve upon my code?

```
% \usepackage[minted]{tcolorbox}
% \tcbuselibrary{skins}
\definecolor{topbar}{RGB}{220,220,220}
\definecolor{main}{RGB}{30,30,30}
\definecolor{quit}{RGB}{248,73,73}
\definecolor{min}{RGB}{252,182,37}
\definecolor{max}{RGB}{41,198,52}
\colorlet{offwhite}{white!96!black}
\newtcblisting{fauxshell}{%
  listing engine=minted, 
  minted language=text, 
  title={\strut}, 
  listing only, 
  enhanced, 
  colbacktitle=topbar, 
  boxrule=0cm,
  left=2mm,
  width=\textwidth,
  frame hidden, 
  colback=main, 
  coltext=offwhite, 
  overlay={
    \fill [fill=quit] ([xshift=3mm]title.west) circle (1mm);
    \fill [fill=min] ([xshift=6mm]title.west) circle (1mm);
    \fill [fill=max] ([xshift=9mm]title.west) circle (1mm);
  }%
}
\begin{fauxshell}
$ echo `date`
Mon Aug 21 09:21:35 CEST 2017
\end{fauxshell}
```